# Thread limited processing in 2.8 builds?

Tags: versions

I have been trying the 2.8 Blender Bot builds. None of them have even attempted to use more than the first 16 processing threads of my Threadripper CPU, leaving 75% of the computing power idle. Many 2.8 features "burn up" these first 16 threads. Is it possible to use these builds across my entire 64 thread CPU?

Comment: By "processing" you mean CPU rendering? Please specify.

Comment: No, not rendering. In this case, sculpt editing a mesh. The 2.8 Windows build blasts away at the first 16 threads, with each stroke, but ignores the rest of the 64 potential threads. If I were to render with the CPU, however, it would still only utilize the first 16 threads. I suspect these builds are inadvertently limited to 8 cores of processing. If it were a trivial change in the builder, it would be great to have the entire 64 threads enabled!

Comment: The rendering is weird, maybe there is some optimization to be done. As a bit offtopic: also try zbrush, it will use all threads nicely. If performance is a concern and you payed that much for your HW you might as well use it, it's way faster with better brushes.

Comment: Some tasks have limits to how far you can reasonably parallelise them, however I would have though that with rendering particularly you should be able to benefit. This is likely a bug and should be reported to https://developer.blender.org/